# How can I tell If a path is like another one?

Tags: python, graph-theory

I have written some code to generate all paths with a given length from a point outwards:

```py
def pathFinder(depth, vertex, path, area, results):
    if depth == 0:
        results.append(path)
        return

    for u in [vertex + off for off in offsets if vertex + off not in [x for x in path] and (vertex + off).within(*area)]:
        path.append(u)
        pathFinder(depth-1, u, list(path), area, results)
        path.pop()
```

This results in a bunch of paths, of which many are alike. For example, these two paths (length 4) have the same shape but go into different directions:

[image: a path]
[image: another path]

I want to look at two given paths and determine if they're "the same" or not.
Now these paths could be *offset, rotated, mirrored or backwards*. How could I know that a path is like another one as previously described? I have limited knowledge of graph theory, but I bet there is some nifty graph theory trick that can solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two paths in a graph are the same if they have:

- the same nodes
- in the same order